# Dash callback 'unexpected EOF while parsing' bug

Tags: python, callback, syntax-error, plotly-dash

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id='my_interval',
            interval=1*1000
        ),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    [Output('output_data', 'children'),
     Output('mybarchart', 'figure')],
    [Input('my_interval', 'n_intervals')]
)
```

The above code throws the error below in lat line of app callback. I am not able to understand where the error is. Can someone help?

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@` for some reason without a following function definition.

`@` is the syntax for a decorator, if you don't have a following function definition then you will get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`.

A simple decorator looks like this:

```py
@decoratorFunctionThatReturnsAnotherFunction
def myDecoratedFunction():
    pass
```

Recommending Corey Schafer's video about decorators on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsAPt_9Bf3U